# Why does my (large) string get cut off when inserting into SQL Server database from Powershell?

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I am trying to insert a large string (49,443 characters) into my SQL Server database from a Powershell script, but for some reason it gets cut off after 43,679 characters. This is my script:

```
$SqlServer = "MyServer";
$SqlCatalog = "MyDatabase";
$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "MyConnectionString"
$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand

$LargeString = gc C:\SomeTextFile.txt -Raw

$SqlQuery = "INSERT INTO MyTable (LargStringColumn) VALUES ('" + $LargeString "')"

$SqlCmd.CommandText = $SqlQuery
$SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection
$SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd
$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$nRecs = $SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
```

The database column is of type varchar(max), which can hold 2GB of data. And my research shows that a powershell string can hold around the same amount of data. And the data that I am actually trying to insert is only a small fraction of this (97KB).

If I do

```
Write-Host $LargeString
```

I can see all the data. The same is true if I use Out-File. I am losing data somehow when my insert command is ran. The data DOES appear in the database, it's just not the entire string.

Why does my string keep getting cut off when it is inserted into the database?

Comment: You need to parametrise. A **literal string** will be treated as a `varchar(8000)` or `nvarchar(4000)` *even* if it's length is larger than that length.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! What would be the correct way to parameterize my $LargeString variable in this particular instance?

Comment: I'm afraid that my Powershell isn't that strong; certainly not on a SQL Server side anyway. I *can* write it, but despite being a dedicated `sql-server` resource on Stack Overflow, I find that my usage of Powershell and SQL Server never overlap; apart from perhaps having SSIS or Agent run a Script that performs more complex file based operations. I **assume**, (as the above reads like C#) that you would use `Parameters.Add`.

Comment: [Here's an article](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/running-parameterized-queries-against-sql-server-using-powershell) that contains some samples for parametrizing queries. Images are missing, but code is there. Can you work from there? I don't have a DB at hand for testing until back at office tomorrow.

Comment: Also your insert is susceptible for injection. If the string itself contains singe quote it will impact your insert. Especially if it contains something like " ');-- ". Use parameters as advised in the previous comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel so embarrassed to answer this, but it turns out my original code was correct and I did not need to parameterize my script (but thanks a lot for the tip, Larnu!). In reality, the entire string *was* being inserted into the database. I would verify the data by copying and pasting the string directly from SSMS into notepad. What I did not know, however, was that SSMS limits how many characters are returned into the result.

I was able to verify everything was working correctly when I pulled the data into an MVC application I had already been working on. I'm guessing a simple export of the data would have worked too!

Also, Piotr, you are absolutely correct. I ended up having to do a $LargString.replace so that all of my individual quotes ' would be replaced with double quotes ". Thanks again everyone for your assistance!

Comment: SSMS' behavior is a common pitfall. One can use [`LEN()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/len-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function to see the string length in a column.